# Nice UI control kit for SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, controls

We are looking for powerful UI control toolkit for ASP.NET SharePoint 2010. We want (in order):

- excellent performance and stability
- wide functionality
- slick look

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answers so far.
In my case UI requirements were so high that we have decided not to use SharePoint in UI at all. We have:

MVC3 (almost all UI)

```
   +
```

BL+DAL+etc

```
   +
```

SharePoint (document storage)